# Сравнение символов в массивах

Tags: java, алгоритм, сравнение, equals

корректно будет использовать оператор "==" для сравнения двух символов из двух массивов? Не адреса в памята а именно совпадение знаков(если так можно сказать)

```
char[] alphabetArr = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'g', 'k'}// тут должен быть весь алфавит
String word = reader.readLine();
char [] arrayOfLetersFromWord = word.toCharArray();
char [] arrayForKeepLeters = new char[word.length()];

 if(arrayOfLetersFromWord[0] == alphabetArr[randomLeter]) //randomLeter привязана к выборке рандомного символа
```

Я понимаю, что для этого используют .equals() но компилятор против. Сообщает мне : Error:(45, 45) java: char cannot be dereferenced и не " собирает" проект.
Что это значит?

Comment: Да. *(11 символов нужно...)*

Comment: char-это примитив, не класс. Методов у него нет.... Если хотите работать с char-ами как с полноценными объектоми, воспользуйтесь классом-обёрткой - Character

Comment: Но сравнение строковых литералов  происходит через equals, а оператор == сравнивает адреса, разве не так?

Comment: @timbars хорошо, спасибо. Буду разбираться.

Comment: Конечно корректно. Именно этот оператор и используется для сравнения двух символов. Можно же просто попробовать `if ('s' == 'd') {...} else {...}` и убедиться.

Answer (score 3):

Как уже написали в комментах, всё зависит от того, что используется, примитивы или их обертки. Примитивы можно сравнивать через '=='. Equals естественно для них не работает, поскольку это не объекты. Если начинаете сравнивать объекты через '==', то, конечно, начинают проверяться уже ссылки. Конкретно в вашем случае: ДА - char  сравниваются через '=='; Если используется обертка Character, как было написано выше, то необходимо уже использовать equals, либо для Character-объекта вызвать метод charValue и применить операцию '=='. По мне, проще работать с примитивами, но опять же, всё зависит от задачи

Comment: Я сравниваю строковые литералы, равна ли буква "а" букве "а" если они хранятся в разных масивах и имеют разный адрес в памяти.

Comment: @CoffeJava две одинаковые строки всегда вернут true, так как класс String переопределяет метод equals и сравниваем строки по их содержимому. И не важно, разный у них адрес в памяти, разные ли ссылки - все равно будет проверка по содержимому строки.

Comment: @CoffeJava Вы сравниваете символьные литералы, а не строковые. Символьный литерал -- один символ в одинарных кавычках. Строковый литерал -- символы в двойных кавычках (или кавычки без символов: пустая строка "").